# How to display a polymer element?

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I am not able to make my custom element appear.

This is the project structure:

[image: structure of the project].

This is the `index.html` file with my element :

```html
<link rel="import" href="./../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">

<dom-module id="neito-sidebar">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <iron-input bind-value="{{mot}}">
           <label for="test">Name : </label>
           <input id="test" type="text"  value="{{mot::input}}">
        </iron-input>
        <span>[[mot]]</span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({is: 'neito-sidebar' });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="./components/neito-sidebar.html">
    <title>Polymer Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <neito-sidebar></neito-sidebar> 
</body>
</html>
```

To open it I opened the local file with Firefox (`file:///C:/...`).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the console / network tab for errors?

Comment: Nope and you were right, there is a dozen of XML error ? Don't really understand them

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, one of the answer is : You need to use a web server to use Polymer. You cannot access it with file:///C:/ ..., So I setup a quick nodejs Express Server just for the developpement of the element and it is working well now. Here is how I do it :

[The project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48vAO.jpg)

The index.html that use my polymer custom elements :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
    <link rel="import" href="./elements/neito-sidebar.html">
    
    <title>Polymer Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <neito-sidebar></neito-sidebar>
</body>
</html>
```

The server app.js (really ultra simple) :

```js
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
const _port = 3000;
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/..', 'public')))

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root: __dirname});
})

.listen(_port, function (){
    console.log('Server listening on : '+_port);
})
```

And the component definition :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="./../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="neito-sidebar">
    <template>
        <style>
            span
            {
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style> 

        <label for="test">Name : </label>
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test">
        <button onclick="_updateSpan">Valider</button>
        <span>{{mot}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'neito-sidebar',
            properties: 
            {
                mot: 
                {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true
                }
            },
            
        _updateSpan: function()
        {
            this.mot = $('#test').val();
        }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

For now the updateSpan doesnt work but the element is displayed :).
So here my auto-answer, have a good day